# Android change activity or orentation from webview

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm develop a webapp no phonegap based. 
For displayed into full-screen mode , i write an andorid app with one activity:
a webview inside a full screen  no action bar holo theme.

Now, my web app work in portrait orientation (so my activity have "orientation:portrait" in manifest)
but there is same page that i want rotate automatically my phone. 
for example:
when i open in jqm page "thisAppPage" i want that my webview change orientation.

where is the best way to do that? 
read metadata and change activity? ecc ecc

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Orientation change would cause your Activity to be recreated. So you need to program accordingly so when the orientation change happens, you get the same content in the activity as you had before the orientation change. You gotta save your state and in onCreate you should use the saved state to bring the activity to its old state.